# Error while connecting jdbc odbc Driver

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

I don't get where i'm doing wrong, the only thing is working is adding record into database.
Deleting and finding code is not working (i do not included auto Generated Code) on netbeans.

> Error type:  java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

enter code here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Connectivity1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection c;
    Statement s;
    ResultSet r;

    public Connectivity1() {
        initComponents();

        try{
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DataC1");
                    s=c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                    r=s.executeQuery("SELECT * from NameN");
                        System.out.println("Connected!");
                        r.next();
            }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);} }


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{
            String id,fname,lname;
                   id=jTextField1.getText();
                fname=jTextField2.getText();
                     lname=jTextField3.getText();
                    s.executeUpdate("insert into NameN values('"+id+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"')");
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record has been added!");
            DBclose();
               DBopen();
     }
        catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
    }  }                



private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{
            String id=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter ID number");
              r=s.executeQuery("select * from NameN where ID = " + id +" ");
             r.next();
           SetText();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
    } }               


private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{

            String id=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter ID number");
             s.executeUpdate("delete * from NameN where ID = "+id+"");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record has been deleted!");
            DBclose();
         DBopen();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
    } }  


public void DBopen(){

    try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DataC1");
                s=c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                r=s.executeQuery("SELECT * from NameN");
                System.out.println("Reconnected!");
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    } }

public void DBclose(){

    try{
            c.close();

            System.out.println("Disconnected!");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);} }


public void SetText(){

    try{                  
            jTextField1.setText(r.getString(1));
            jTextField2.setText(r.getString(2));
            jTextField3.setText(r.getString(3));
            System.out.println("text displayed!");
    }

  catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the `ID` in single quotes(`''`) since it is String data type

> select * from NameN where ID='value'

code should be,

```
 s.executeUpdate("delete * from NameN where ID = '"+id+"'");
```

and

```
r=s.executeQuery("select * from NameN where ID = '" + id +"'");
```